# Is this dog a pitbull?

Tags: dogs

Can anyone understand what is this dog's race? It looks like a pit-bull. If not what kind of dog is this? Is this dangerous when it grows for my cats?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because breed recognition is off-topic. Please read [this meta post](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/q/410/12501) for the reasons and more information. Additionally to that, every dog can potentially be a danger to cats, regardless of its breed, just like a pit bull can be a very calm and loving dog. The breed, upbringing, training and interactions with the owners and innate personality traits all form the character of a dog.

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't aware of your dog's pedigree, it's pretty likely your dog is a mix, but there is no way to really know for sure without genetic testing.

As to the question of "is it a pit bull," it also depends on what you are asking. There is an actual breed of dog known as the American Pit Bull Terrier. And of course, no one can tell if your dog is of that breed for sure without genetic testing.

But people also use the word "pit bull" to mean a general type of dog rather than a specific breed. They will apply it to mixes of a specific body type, as well as multiple distinct breeds of a similar body type such as the American Pit Bull Terrier, the American Staffordshire Terrier, American Bully, and the Staffordshire Bull Terrier. Your dog fits into this body type, so in that sense, yes, it is a pit bull. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pit_bull

As to the question, "is it a danger to cats," that is also unknown. The breed may have some correlation towards a tendency to aggression with cats, but it's by no means the rule. Rather, it's all dependent on the individual disposition of the dog.

Pit bulls in particular have an undeserved reputation for aggression, probably because the pit bull look is associated with dog fighting, or because there are many, many dogs that fit into the class "pit bull," and they are very probably more likely to have inexperienced owners, versus another breed you have to go out of your way to try to acquire. But any dog mistreated or badly trained in that fashion would likely be aggressive also.